# TypeScript interface evaluation

Tags: typescript

My colleague came across weird behavior of typescript. Combine says that it will always be `BasicModel` however it should be `BasicModel | ExtraModel`. Do you know why this is happening?

```
interface ExtraModel {
  both: string;
  extra: string;
}

interface BasicModel {
  both: string;
}

const extra = { both: '', extra: '' } as ExtraModel;
const basic = { both: '' } as BasicModel;

const combined = (true as boolean) ? extra : basic;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIA8xTgWQPYAmEANsgN4BQyyARnmABYBcyAzlqAOYDcVyEmbC3ZQuvAL4UKoSLEQoAQnFbAE+IqUrU6jYRxA8Kkigjwh2-QXGQBecrXrNkAcmcAaS1jgtXyccmU0K3USXlNzMFplVVt7HSdff0ClFTVCUKlwi1MAWxpQCAJYgAosAFcUQLo8Ygg4EABKZAB+T2xkFhpohG4gA)

Comment: `BasicModel` is equvivalent to `BasicModel | ExtraModel`, because you have only the `both` property in both cases

Comment: the comment by @ShamPooSham is correct, and it's probably best to create `ExtraModel` like `interface ExtraModel extends BasicModel`

Comment: This is part of subtype reduction. If you have a union A | B and B is a subtype of A you are just left with A. This is also evident in unions such as `string | "some string" which simplify to `string`